# Need help inserting an inline image within a Google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm currently having difficulties adding a footer image to a MailApp.sendEmail function. For context, this function takes in data from a google form, inserts it into a template, then emails the completed template to the user. Everything about it works except for the inline image. I've tried looking at many tutorials online for the proper implementation but I feel like my syntax is still wrong. I would like to add the "sigPic" image to the end of the email, but I also want it resized since its quite big. Currently, the email sends but the image does not. A very small white square with a red cross going through it appears instead.  This is my current code:

```
  var sigPic = DriveApp.getFileById('1QfB9rjVPAEclwKnqzF7Ex7priN3389Ie');
  var inlineImages = {};
  inlineImages[sigPic.getId()] = sigPic.getBlob();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Video Footage Request Recieved - " + caseNumber,
    htmlBody: "<p>Thank you for submitting your Video Footage Request for case number " + caseNumber + ". Our team will process your request soon and get back to you if we need anything else.</p>" + 
    "<br><img src='cid: sigPic.getId()' + style='width:414px; height:82px;'/>", // problem line
    inlineImages: inlineImages,
    attachments: [copyDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]

  });
```

The "// problem line" is the line where I think my syntax is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to insert your default signature into the email?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

When you provide the image source in `src='cid: sigPic.getId()'`, you are not providing the ID of this image, but the string "sigPic.getId()", which is absolutely not the same as the ID (the actual key image). Since this doesn't match any key in `inlineImages`, the image is not referenced.

#### Solution:

You should provide JS code instead, which should be outside string quotes.

Modify the "problem line" the following way. From this:

```js
"<br><img src='cid: sigPic.getId()' + style='width:414px; height:82px;'/>",
```

To this:

```js
"<br><img src='cid:" + sigPic.getId() + "' + style='width:414px; height:82px;'/>",
```

#### Reference:

- [MailApp.sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))